# Undefined control sequence and Something's missing perhaps a missing \item

Tags: errors, algorithms

I am using Windows 7 and getting a LaTeX Error in an algorithm; I am new to LaTeX and already spent a lot of time to figure this out but no luck. Could you please help me here?

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate Tree Labelling.}
\label{alg:treeLabel}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\While{ S is not empty}{
Pop out top vertex from S. Let v=S.pop().\\
}
 \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Latex Error:

```
 Something's wrong -- perhaps a missing \item. 
         Pop out top vertex from S. Let v=S.pop()
        ! Undefined control sequence.
        \while
              {S is not empty}{   
        Something's wrong -- perhaps a missing \item. 
         \end{algorithm}.
```

Please help here.

Comment: Your code snippet has `\While`, while your error message says `\while`; are these the same, or is one a typo, or..?  (Note that *TeX is case-sensitive when it comes to things, unlike Windows, which does not always distinguish between upper- and lowercase words.)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate Tree Labelling.}
\label{alg:treeLabel}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While {S is not empty}
\State {Pop out top vertex from S. Let v=S.pop().}
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

When using `\While`, you should close with `\EndWhile`, that is the main cause of the error. Besides, the statement `Pop out top vertex from S. Let v=S.pop().` should be put after a `\State` command to get it correctly indented and no need for `\\`s.

**More examples with ELSE IF**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate Tree Labelling.}
\label{alg:treeLabel}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While {S is not empty}
\State {Pop out top vertex from S. Let v=S.pop().}
\EndWhile

\If {Expression 1} 
  \If {Expression 2}
      \State Statement 1.
      \State Statement 2. 
  \EndIf
  \ElsIf {Expression 3}
      \State  Statement 3.
      \State  Statement 4.
  \Else
      \State  Statement 4.
\EndIf

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how we write `\ElsIf` and not `\ElseIf`.